# Is there a way to change document's default view in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

The doc and its all fields are expanded by default, but I need it to be shrunk because it's huge. I couldn't find a setting in settings. (although I found the dark mode which is cool)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the `Dev Tools` tab: 
Then afaik, the only thing to do is to limit the fields you're fetching.
ex.

```
GET /_search
{
    "_source": "obj.*",
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

ref --> [Elasticsearch Page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering)

---

**But**, if you're talking about the `Discover` tab, then you just need to press on the `+` on the fields on the left side to show only the selected ones.

hope that answers your question.

Comment: I was talking about Dev Tools. +1 for very useful comment and ref, but not quite the answer I needed. (Though, I am not sure if Kibana has the skill I wanted)